# Mutation when updating a Svelte writable store that is an object

Tags: svelte

I have a writable store that is an object:

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const myStore = writable({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```

Coming from redux, I wonder, can I mutate it?:

```js
myStore.update((prev) => {
  prev.a++;
  return prev;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just mutate it. It is what happens if you use `$`-syntax anyway, e.g.

```html
<button on:click={() => $myStore.a++} />
```

That would just mutate the store and fire a change notification via `set`.